# Making an Agent touch an Object in Second Life

Tags: lua, linden-scripting-language

Does anyone know of any way possible through either 3rd party viewers that have automation features, usually with LUA (CoolVL, Radegast), RLV/LSL or any other way to make the agent touch an object in a scripted/automated fashion in Second Life? Thanks for the insight.

I've explored LSL and came to the conclusion it's not possible using LSL. (Though I'd be happy to be proven wrong if anyone knows anything more.) I've also searched CoolVL documentation but see no mention of achieving this result.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [**Corrade**](https://grimore.org/secondlife/scripted_agents/corrade), it has a feature wherein it will order a scripted agent to touch a prim:

https://grimore.org/secondlife/scripted_agents/corrade/api/commands/touch